# Assembly language CALL instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

(CS) = 1075H, (IP) = 0300H, before executing the following instruction:

CALL 1000H

To what address is program control passed? What is the new value of CS and IP after the instruction
is executed?

Comment: (CS) = 1075H, (IP) = 1000H

Comment: can you explain abit how IP become 1000H?

Comment: call pushes the current IP (to be able to return there), and jumps to the adress given. so "call 1000" jumps to 1000, and the IP there is 1000

Comment: Have you tried it out with a debugger?  I think you'll find that you can answer your own question very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

To answer this question, think about what the `call` instruction does.
If you are not sure, then [look it up](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html):

> When executing a far call in real address or virtual-8086 mode, the processor pushes the current value of both the CS and EIP registers onto the stack for use as a return-instruction pointer. The processor then performs a "far branch" to the code segment and offset specified with the target operand for the called procedure.
>
> Here the target operand specifies an absolute far address either directly with a pointer (ptr16:16 or ptr16:32) or indirectly with a memory location (m16:16 or m16:32). With the pointer method, the segment and offset of the called procedure is encoded in the instruction, using a 4-byte (16-bit operand size) or 6-byte (32-bit operand size) far address immediate. With the indirect method, the target operand specifies a memory location that contains a 4-byte (16-bit operand size) or 6-byte (32-bit operand size) far address. The operand-size attribute determines the size of the offset (16 or 32 bits) in the far address. The far address is loaded directly into the CS and EIP registers. If the operand-size attribute is 16, the upper two bytes of the EIP register are cleared.

You are told that `IP` (the Instruction Pointer) is `300H`, and that `CS` (the Code Segment) is `1075H`. What does the documentation say is going to happen?

1. First, `CS` and `IP` will be pushed onto the stack for later use when returning from the call.
2. Then, the processor branches to the specified code segment and offset.
   In this case, that will be `1000H`.

   How will that affect `CS` and `IP`? Well, `CS` will be the same because you haven't changed segments, but `IP` will change. Why will `IP` change? Think about what `IP` *is*: it is a pointer to the instruction that is about to be executed. If execution jumps to `1000H`, then the instruction about to be executed is obviously at `1000H`, so `IP` will be `1000H`.

What happens after you `ret` from the `call`? The old `CS` and `IP` (the ones that were pushed onto the stack by `call`) are popped off. `CS` still won't change, but `IP` will now be `300H` again!

(Note that this will *not* create an infinite loop. Why? Because of the way that `IP` works. It is set internally during instruction decoding to point to the *next* instruction to be executed. Therefore, when the `call` instruction is being executed, `IP` points to the instruction *after* call. Therefore, when you return and pop `IP`, you will start executing *after* the `call`.)

Comment: I sort of miss the information how the "current `ip`" during `call` doing `push ip` is actually already pointing at next instruction (because `call` instruction was already decoded and `ip` updated internally) after the `call` one.  ... with your description literally (IP is 300h again) the `ret` would create infinite loop. :)

Comment: Well, no, it wouldn't create an infinite loop, precisely because `IP` works the way you describe. I guess I should include that explicitly in the answer.

Comment: Hm... I wonder, what really means *"(IP) = 0300H, before executing"* in OP. It's a bit ambivalent, can be understood both as `org 300h` or as *before executing* (after decode), then the `call` being at 02FD (for `call rel16` variant). I think this may be confusing for people without the knowledge of CPU internal processing and difference between execution and decoding step.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the case with so many of these homework-style questions. The more you know, the harder and more confusing they become.

Comment: Why are you assuming that this is a `far` call?  In NASM, `call 1000h` assembles to the [`call rel16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) encoding, which is a near call and only pushes IP, not CS:IP.  To get a direct far call to the same segment, you'd have to write something like `call 1075H:1000H` (i.e. hard-code the current CS value).  Hmm, I wonder if you can emulate a far call with `push cs` / `call rel16`; I forget if the segment value goes at the higher address.

Comment: I mostly assumed it was a far call because the question gave the CS value. It doesn't really matter though in this case. An assembler can always encode a near call as a far call if it wants to, and I didn't want to overcomplicate the explanation!

Comment: That moment when you give simple task to student ... and three asm experts ponder over it for hours... (funny)

Comment: *An assembler can always encode a near call as a far call if it wants to*.   Not a sane assembler!  Near calls don't push `CS`, and I don't think you mean it could emit a far-call followed by `add sp, 2`.  Also, the assembler would have to hard-code the current value of CS into the instruction, which the programmer would not be expecting if they wrote a near call.  (This could matter in a position-independent block that needs to run with two difference CS:IP values for the same linear address, or just if the assembler gets the wrong CS value.)

Comment: Also, I wish I didn't know all this obsolete 16-bit stuff.  Thanks, Stack Overflow, for being full of questions about 16-bit crap (and not just bootloaders or toy OSes).  Anyway, I think the question mentions CS as a way to check that the student understands that a near call modifies IP but not CS, and that this is a near call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there were DOS assemblers that always emitted far calls even when you only needed a near call, depending on the "model" that you were targeting. Position-independent code compatibility didn't matter, because there was no such thing as PIC. I agree this is a very foolish assembler and certainly defies expectations, but it does work. Then again, I could be completely wrong here. I know very little about the obsolete 16-bit stuff. That was very much before my time, and although I've picked up bits and pieces from reading articles online, I haven't tried to remember it all.

Comment: I'm certainly not attached to this answer. If someone wants to post a better one, I'll delete it.